# Distribution problem where |a|, |b|, |c|, and |d| are at most 10. Check my work?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, probability-distributions

How many ways can a+b+c+d=18, where a,b,c,d are integers such that $|a|,\ |b|,\ |c|,\ |d|$
 are each at most 10?

This is what I have so far. If all four numbers have the restriction -10 =< a, b, c, d, =< 10, than we can add 11 to each number, where

w = a+11,
x = b+11,
y = c+11,
z = d+11

w+x+y+z = 29. Would it be $C(28,3)$ or did I overcount some numbers?

Comment: Why is $w + x + y + z = 29$?

Comment: @Arthur Oh I see. I should add 44, not 11 to 18 on the RHS. w+x+y+z = 62?

Comment: Yes. I'm still trying to understand the second part.

Comment: @Arthur Are you referring to the $C(28,3)$, (though that would be $C(61,3)$ now) part? That is just regular distribution

Comment: So you are looking for $1 \leq w,x,y,z \leq 21$ such that $w+x+y+z = 62$. Why are there $28 \choose 3$ (or $61 \choose 3$ I guess) ways for that?

Comment: @Arthur Hmm. I forgot about the restriction for w, x, y, z. That would change the combinatorial.

Comment: Well you can simply count down the options ($2284$) and see if it matches your formula.

Comment: @Arthur So if w = 21-d, x = 21-e, y = 21-f, and z = 21-g, than w+x+y+z = 84-(d+e+f+g) = 84-62 = 22. Would the # of solutions then be $C(21, 3)$?

Comment: @barakmanos that would be a lot of counting..

Comment: @MathisLife: Python interpreter didn't seem to mind that when I asked him (or her) to do it.

Comment: @barakmanos I don't have a problem with it...but shouldn't individually counting each case be a last resort, as it takes a lot of calculations?

Comment: @MathisLife his point was that if you are handy with programming for and while loops in java/python/c/etc... then you can always write a program to brute force an answer (which seems to be how barak got to the [correct] answer of 2284).  While not elegant, it can sometimes be more feasible than coming up with an analytical approach to certain problems.

Comment: @JMoravitz: My point was - OP already has what he/she thinks is the correct analytic solution, and is now asking us to verify it. So I just meant to say that there was an easier method for verification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a balls and urns problem solvable using a combination of inclusion-exclusion and stars&bars

$|a|\leq 10 \Rightarrow -10\leq a \leq 10$.  Make a change of variable $x_1 = a+10\Rightarrow 0\leq x_1 \leq 20$

Do similarly to the other letters, so we are at $x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 = (a+10) + (b+10) + (c+10) + (d+10) = (a+b+c+d)+40 = 18+40 = 58$

Number of ways in which no upper bound conditions are violated = number of ways without upper bound condition - number of ways at least one condition is violated + number of ways two conditions are violated - number of ways 3 conditions are violated + number of ways 4 conditions are violated.

To violate one upper bound condition (say for example $x_1$) then $x_1>20\Rightarrow x_1\geq 21$ make a change of variable $y_1 = x_1 - 21$.  Then $0\leq y_1$ and $y_1+x_2+x_3+x_4 = 37$.  As there were 4 choices for which was the offending $x$, we multiply by 4.

Do similarly for the case of two violating terms.  Note for 3 or 4 violating terms, it is impossible.

$ = \binom{58+4-1}{4-1} - 4\cdot \binom{37+4-1}{4-1} + 6\cdot\binom{16+4-1}{4-1} - 0 + 0 = 2284$

---

It should be mentioned in case you haven't seen stars&bars, to find the number of integer solutions of $x_1 + x_2 + \dots + x_r = n$ where each $x_i\geq 0$, there are $\binom{n+r-1}{r-1}$ number of solutions.

Comment: That seems just about right.